# Bootstrap 4 - background image for <body> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm using Bootstrap Studio to learn how to code.I have added a body background image and set the navbar background to none and that works fine.

I am facing a problem regarding the next components added, in this case a jumbotron and a button. Each one of these two components are going over the image set in the `<body>` which is logical. What I want is to create a navbar transparent and to have a background image, but only for the jumbotron and the navbar. How can I achieve this?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

**Here is the HTML code**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="jumbotron" id="first-jumbo">
            <h1>Heading text</h1>
            <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-link">brand </a>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">second item</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                             <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                             <li class="divider"></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                             <li class="divider"></li>
                             <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Here is the CSS code**

```
body {
  background:url(../../assets/img/pexels-photo-294560.jpeg) no-repeat;
  padding-top:100px;
  background-size:cover;
}

.navbar {
  background:none;
}

#first-jumbo {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Here is a [page preview](http://magic-sun-0850.bss.design/)

Comment: "What I want is to create a navbar transparent and to have a background image" do you want a transparent background or not?

Comment: I do, but setting a background image for the body seems not be a solution.

Comment: I've posted a solution, hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
  background:url(../../assets/img/pexels-photo-294560.jpeg) no-repeat !important;
  padding-top:100px;
  background-size:cover;
}

.navbar, #first-jumbo  {
  background: transparent !important;
}

#first-jumbo {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I want something like on this page https://www.creative-tim.com/

You see the navbar and the background image and below the pills? I want something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to transparent jumbotron?
Use,

`#first-jumbo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}`

Comment: If you are not sure what the question is , you should probably first ask in comment and then answer.